# Creating a table that exists of two variables in PHP with PDO without quotes around the table name

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

So I have this PHP code to create a table. It should create a table called test101_list1, but instead it creates a table called 'test101'_'list1'. Without the backslash, PDO will see it as :username_ instead of :username. Also, I'd like to get rid of the quotes around the username and list name, but I still want to sanitize the input, as it uses user input. How can I do this?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("CREATE TABLE `lists`.`:username\_:listname` ( `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `lang1` TEXT NOT NULL , `lang2` TEXT NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':listname', $listname);

$username = "test101";
$listname = "list1";

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Update: I just realized I can just put the two variables together before doing to PDO stuff. I don't know how to avoid the quotes around the table name though.

Comment: @mega6382 They are trying to select from and insert stuff into a table that already exists. I'm trying to create a new one. Also, they use MySQLi, while I prefer to use PDO.

Comment: Don't look at the question look at the answer.

Comment: The answer is still with MySQLi and says you should use a whitelist, which isn't really possible when creating a table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

Comment: @RyanVincent I mean, it works, as it creates the table, it's just not a good idea because of the quotes around it. So that's why I wanted to know how to do this without using prepared statements, but still sanitizing the input (using PDO). Does PDO have a "normal" sanitize function?

Comment: But that puts quotes around the string: pretty much the opposite of what I'm trying.